# How to check if an element is the body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

From chrome console:

```
var body = $("body");
=>  undefined
body
=>  [<body class=​"ask-page">​…​</body>​]
body.tagName
=>  undefined
body.nodeName
=>  undefined
```

So if I have an element reference, how can I know if it's the body?

(JQuery welcome!)

Comment: jQuery nodes have no properties. Only methods. `.prop("tagMame")`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have a jQuery object

```
var isBody = $obj.is('body'); // true or false
```

Answer (score 17):

Try this comparison with sample usage of plain JavaScript and jQuery:

```javascript
function isBody(el) {
  return document.body === el;
}

isBody(document.getElementById('child').parentElement); // => true
isBody($('#child').parent().get(0)); // => true
```

Comment: would need `el.get(0)` if its a jquery object remember

Comment: @Chimoo: ya, the sample usage in the last line demonstrates that.

Answer (score 4):

```
var isBody = $(this).prop("tagName").toLowerCase() == 'body';
```

Comment: FYI other answers are possibly more efficient

Comment: document.body === el is one comparison. My answer contains a call to 3 different functions plus a string comparsion

Answer (score 0):

```
var elm = $('body');
if (elm.is('body')) { // do stuff for example
}
```